# IndexOutOfRangeException in CsvWriter

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm getting a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` while trying to serialize a dataset of dynamic objects.  It's not any single row since I've tested it with each individual row (there are only four in my example).  It's happening in the `CsvWriter.HasAnyEscapeChars` function.  The exact stack trace is:

```
   at ServiceStack.Text.CsvWriter.HasAnyEscapeChars(String value)
   at ServiceStack.TextExtensions.ToCsvField(Object text)
   at ServiceStack.Text.CsvDictionaryWriter.WriteObjectRow(TextWriter writer, IEnumerable`1 row)
   at ServiceStack.Text.CsvDictionaryWriter.Write(TextWriter writer, IEnumerable`1 records)
   at ServiceStack.Text.CsvWriter`1.Write(TextWriter writer, IEnumerable`1 records)
   at ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer`1.WriteObject(TextWriter writer, Object value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.SerializeToStream[T](T value, Stream stream)
   at <my code>
```

It looks (from the source code) that `HasAnyEscapeChars` needs to add a guard against an empty string since the reference to value[0] will fail there, though I'm not seeing how that would actually happen in actual usage.

```
public static bool HasAnyEscapeChars(string value)
{
  return CsvConfig.EscapeStrings.Any(value.Contains)
     || value[0] == JsWriter.ListStartChar
     || value[0] == JsWriter.MapStartChar;
}
```

Is there something I need to do to sanitize my data or is it a bug?

Comment: Well, do you think it is meaningful that CsvWriter throws an IndexOutOfRangeException when checking for escape characters? If you think it is meaningful -> no bug. If you think it is not meaningful -> quite likely a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IndexOutOfRangeException` should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/36313cfa5544cfc345bd1bfd030e27676d292bc4).

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response.  Also, thanks for all you do with ServiceStack!